# R - Decision tree has only one branch

Tags: r

```
    > queimaduras
     Cabelo   Pele LocaoSolar Queimadura
1  Castanho Morena        Nao        sem
2     Louro Morena        Nao    ligeira
3     Louro Morena        Sim        sem
4     Louro Branca        Sim        sem
5     Louro Branca        Nao      grave
6     Ruivo Branca        Sim      grave
7  Castanho Branca        Nao        sem
8     Ruivo Morena        Nao    ligeira
9     Ruivo Morena        Sim    ligeira
10 Castanho Branca        Sim        sem
```

I've used the tree, ctree and rpart packages and none seem to work.
My objective is the Queimaduras column.
It seams like they only work with data with numbers insted of words like in this case. Any ideas?

```
tree_model = tree(Queimadura~Cabelo + Pele + LocaoSolar, queimaduras)
```

rpart says: Error in plot.rpart(ctree) : fit is not a tree, just a root

Comment: Are you using factors?

Comment: not quite sure what factors are. I'm pretty new to r.

Comment: What do you mean by "none seem to work"? Are you getting error messages? If so, add them to your question.

Comment: rpart says:Error in plot.rpart(ctree) : fit is not a tree, just a root.  The others show a tree with only two branches

Comment: Check `?as.factor`. Probably just need to convert each variable to a factor with `queimaduras$Cabelo <- as.factor(queimaduras$Cabelo)` (in the case of the variable Cabelo).

Comment: I've tried that for each variable, but the result is the same. Just two branches.

Comment: Then check the default options in `?tree.control` (for the `tree` function). Especially the `minsize` option. There is also a corresponding function `rpart.control`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we figured out that you definetly used factors, my guess is that your problem is just sample size related. You only have 10 observations and the minimum size for a node is in case of the `tree` function by default 10. In case of the rpart package this option is labeled `minsplit` and its default value is 20.
You can change that value. I used the following line to create a tree with more branches:

```
rpart(Queimadura~Cabelo + Pele + LocaoSolar, 
      data=queimaduras, control = rpart.control("minsplit" = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me!